# Pass Javascript array to controller using JQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to pass value of selected  input checkbox to controller using Jquery Ajax.

```js
var selected = [];
$('.myCheckBox input:checked').each(function() {
    selected.push($(this).attr('value'));
});

$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("test", "Display")',
    type: 'GET',
    data: {
        MySelectdFile: selected
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    traditional: true,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function(data) {
        alert("OK")
    }
},
error: function(xhr, status, error) {
    var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
    alert(err.Message);
}, complete: function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
}
});
```

```cs
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult test(string[] MySelectdFile) 
{
  foreach(string item in MySelectdFile) 
  {
    //Do Something
  }
}
```

When   my Javascript array length is small ,everything works fine, but when my Javascript array length is big ,nothing happened.

Comment: Either delete the `contentType: 'application/json',` **OR**  delete `traditional: true,` and change to `data: JSON.stringify({ MySelectdFile: selected }),` ad it need to be a POST, not a GET

Comment: `type: 'GET'` => use `type: 'POST'` for large arrays. Also try removing `contentType: 'application/json'` because you want to pass an array.

Comment: `nothing happened` what about in the browser **developer** tools console? any errors/warnings/messages?

Comment: @JaromandaX See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request. It said 8KB maximum for URL query string.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - doesn't say anything about the limit on the server side - which, according to the answer below is 2KB - also, assuming 8KB is bad - since the same answer states that safari limit is 2KB - when dealing with multiple browsers, you take into consideration what they can ALL do, not the outliers :p

Answer (score 2):

Try change the type from GET to POST from ajax call and from Controller ([HttpGet] to [HttpPost])
Remember:

> when sending data, the GET method adds the data to the URL; and the
>   length of a URL is limited (**maximum URL length is 2048 characters**)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be replace **GET** to **POST**